# Exporting layers as CSV-files using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, ppygis

I am trying to export several layers as CSV-files since I need to analyze them in another software. However, I cannot get my code to work. I am new to Python. Currently working in QGis 3.10.9. I would like all the fields in the attribute table to get exported. Here is the code I am using:

```
file_path = "/Users/user/Desktop/gis/Vikter/NUTS_ID_AT111978Q1.gpkg"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(file_path, "NUTS_ID_AT111978Q1", "ogr")
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "/Users/user/Desktop/gis/Excel/NUTS_ID_AT111978Q1.csv", "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

The error message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Comment: have you tried removing the 'r' before the filename, I'm pretty sure it only applies for windows path.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have reworked the code a bit and tried again. My post is updated.

Comment: Can you try QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "/Users/user/Desktop/gis/Excel/NUTS_ID_AT111978Q1.csv", "utf-8", layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])

Comment: That works but it becomes a .gpkg file.

Comment: then adding driverName = "CSV" should do the trick as it didn't accept the invalid crs provided.https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. 
Can't mark this as solved though, since it is not a standalone post(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is :

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,
"/Users/user/Desktop/gis/Excel/NUTS_ID_AT111978Q1.csv",
"utf-8",driverName = "CSV" , layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

using r".." in linux was part of the error are this is a shortcut for windows path formatting.

The second mistake was passing none as a projection. Specifying the drivename as it is a keyword argument as the layer option seemed to have solved it.