# Create temporary layer from output in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have the given code used to obtain a distance matrix between a source layer (`sLayer`) and a target layer (`tLayer`). The output containing `sfeat.id(), tfeat.id(), dist_pl` is printed in the console but I would like to have that information in a temporary layer. How could I proceed?

```
sLayerName = "Centroids_site"
tLayerName = "Centroids_lotiss"
sLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(sLayerName)
sLayer = sLayers[0]
# Distance between all features from two different layers
tLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(tLayerName)
tLayer = tLayers[0]
sFeats = sLayer.getFeatures()
print(sLayer.featureCount())
for sfeat in sFeats:
    sgeom = sfeat.geometry()
    tFeats = tLayer.getFeatures()
    for tfeat in tFeats:
        tgeom = tfeat.geometry()
        dist_pl = sgeom.distance(tgeom)
        print(sfeat.id(), tfeat.id(), dist_pl)
    print(sfeat.id(), 'done')
```

The code for the distance matrix come from "OpenSourceOptions" https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-measure-the-distance-between-geometries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
sLayerName = "Centroids_site"
tLayerName = "Centroids_lotiss"
sLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(sLayerName)[0]
tLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(tLayerName)[0]

# make new memory layer
dist_layer = QgsVectorLayer("None?field=sid:integer&field=tid:integer&field=dist:double", "dist", "memory")

dist_layer.startEditing()

for sfeat in sLayer.getFeatures():
    sgeom = sfeat.geometry()
    for tfeat in tLayer.getFeatures():
        dist_pl = sfeat.geometry().distance(tfeat.geometry())
        
        # make new feature
        feat = QgsFeature(dist_layer.fields())
        feat["sid"] = sfeat.id()
        feat["tid"] = tfeat.id()
        feat["dist"] = dist_pl
        
        # add the feature to the table
        dist_layer.addFeature(feat)

dist_layer.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(dist_layer)
```